# Generate multiple scatter plots on the same canvas from a dataframe's columns

Tags: r, line, scatter-plot

`df` is a dataframe comprising 10 rows and 5 columns. The row names are '1', '2', ..., '10', in order, whereas the column names are 'A', B', ..., 'E', in order. The values in `df`'s cells are numeric. Each column represents a function that maps the number labeling each row to the corresponding cell value. I would like to draw five scatter point plots on the same canvas, depicting the functions defined by the five columns. Additionally, for each function I'd like each dot to be connected by lines to its two "neighbors" (on the left and on the right).

How would the code need to be modified in order to draw the five functions on separate canvases?

Thank you.

---

Attempted solution of a simplified problem.

```
> row_labels <- (1 : 10)
> col_labels <- (1 : 3)
> raw_data <- outer(row_labels, col_labels, FUN = '^')
> df <- as.data.frame(raw_data)
> dimnames(df) <- list(row_labels, col_labels)
> plot(row_labels, df[['1']])
> lines(row_labels, df[['1']])
> points(row_labels, df[['2']])
> lines(row_labels, df[['2']])
> points(row_labels, df[['3']])
> lines(row_labels, df[['3']])
```

Problems with this solution:

1. The second and third function graphs exceed the canvas.
2. Is there a shorter, more elegant way to accomplish this task?
3. Is there a way to create three plots on three separate canvases in a short and elegant way?

Comment: Sounds like a HW assignment to me. Persons posing such questions are expected to present specific data objects built with code and to show their own efforts at coding. Then we offer advice on how to get over the obstacles.

Comment: @BondedDust: I've added an attempted solution.

Comment: Try: `matplot(df, type="b")` to solve your first problem and I'd robably use lattice::xyplot for the second. There are lots of worked solutions on SO for the latter.

Comment: @BondedDust: Thank you. 'matplot' is exactly what I was looking for. Almost. Instead of little circles, the graph displays the digits 1, 2, and 3 for the points of the corresponding function. Is there any way to show little circles?

Comment: The base plotting functions use 'cex' to control plotting parameters. Try reading the help page for the function.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
# your data
raw_data <- as.data.frame(outer(1:10, 1:3, FUN = '^'))
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C")

#plot it
plot(df$A,type="n",ylim=range(df),ylab="")  # just creates "canvas"
lapply(df,points,type="b")                  # this does the plotting
```

[image]

**EDIT**: response to OP's comment.

```
rows     <- c(1, 3, 7, 8, 16, 19, 20, 24, 28, 30)
df       <- as.data.frame(outer(rows, 1:3, FUN = '^'))
colnames(df) <- c("A","B","C")
rownames(df) <- rows

plot(df$A,type="n",ylim=range(df),xlim=range(rows),ylab="") 
lapply(df,points,x=as.integer(rownames(df)),type="b")
```

[image]

```
par(mfrow=c(1,3))
lapply(df,plot,x=as.integer(rownames(df)),type="b",ylab="")
```

[image]

You should know that the tortured syntax above is solely because the x-values are in the row names - a really, really bad idea.

Comment: Thanks. This looks really good. However, when replacing 1:10 with a less well-behaved sequence, such as c(1, 3, 7, 8, 16, 19, 20, 24, 28, 30), the tick-marks are still 1:10. How can I force the tick marks to be the numbers from the above indicated list?